# How to get data from next page and then move to another one in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Trying to scrape data from a site containing multiple pages. However, I'm getting nothing after running this code. There may be some missing point which I'm unable to point out. Would you like to point out so I could get output from the print statement.
Here is the Spider file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class SaabSpider(Spider):
name = 'saab'
allowed_domains = ['thesaabsite.com/parts_om.php']
start_urls = ['http://www.thesaabsite.com/parts_om.php']

def parse(self, response):
    catagories=response.xpath('//ul[@class="nav col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"]/li/a/text()').extract()
    year_page_url=response.xpath('//ul[@class="nav col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"]/li/a/@href').extract()
    for j in year_page_url:
        absolute_url=response.urljoin(j)
        yield Request(absolute_url,callback=self.model_page)




def model_page(self,response):
    year=response.xpath('//li[@class="tab-pane first text-center"]/a/text()').extract()
    year_url=response.xpath('//li[@class="tab-pane first text-center"]/a/@href').extract()
    for y in year:
        print '\n'
        print y

def main_part(self,response):
    pass
```

After running it in the command prompt. I'm getting this output!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltIy4.png)

Comment: better include the input as code/text instead of a screenshot

Comment: @Patrick the screenshot attached is just to show you that there no output after running the code.

Comment: @patrick **Would you like to point out an error which does not allow to get printed data**

Comment: you should inspect next page link then go with xpath to request the next page.

Comment: @LandOwner this is what the last lines in for loop is doing. But I'm getting no output.